# DBD: Can't load driver file apr_dbd_mysql.so with HTTP basic Auth usind MySql DB

Tags: mysql, basic-authentication, dbd

After I decided to move from file based to DB based auth, I got this error while restarting my apache:

```
DBD: Can't load driver file apr_dbd_mysql.so [Failed]
```

Any reason why is this happening?
I browsed internet and at many places it was written that the dependent package has now been deprecated and cannot install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql package. I am using Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably installed Apache Portable Runtime (APR) does not include MySQL support. You need to rebuild it with option "MySQL Database Support".

For FreeBSD:

```
cd /usr/ports/devel/apr1
make config
```

Check "MySQL Database Support" and

```
make reinstall clean
```

Answer (score -1):

with Debian : aptitude install libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql